# What happens when all seed nodes in Cassandra are down? Can new nodes join the cluster at that point?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

What happens when all seed nodes in Cassandra are down? Can new nodes join the cluster at that point ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is from cassandra docs

> The ring can operate or boot without a seed; **however, you will not be able to add new nodes to the cluster**. It is recommended to configure multiple seeds in production system.
>   `

Here is the link http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/faq/index.html#does-single-seed-mean-single-point-of-failure

Answer (score 4):

The seed nodes are the initial point of contact for bootstrapping nodes. If you have a cluster of say 10 nodes you can ideally might have say 3 nodes as seeds. Once the bootstrapping node contacts the seed it will then start to gossip with other nodes.

*There is nothing special about a seed node in terms of its functionality, it will operate exactly the same as other nodes (seed nodes do gossip more though see doc link below)*

So if per chance your 3 seed nodes were down you could just add an IP of any other node in the cluster to your new node under the `seeds:` parameter in the `cassandra.yaml` file and you'll still be able to bootstrap.

It is of course nice to have all nodes using the same seeds like, for purposes of configuration consistency.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html#reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__seed_provider